# Estimate Arrival Time of a Signal

Tags: discrete-signals, python, reference-implementation

I'm looking for a Python package or method to accurately estimate the **arrival time** of time signals.

A single time signal is stored inside a 1-dimensional numpy array, so every component of the array represents the value of the signal at a given timestep.

Here is an example of the signals shape:

[image: enter image description]

Setting a threeshold is not always efficient, it depends on the signal behaviour and amplitude.

I would like to find a **gradient based method** to identify the starting timestep.
Do you have any relevant experience or suggestion?

Comment: Does this have to be done in real-time?  If not, there are many more options available.

Comment: No they are data from a tsunami simulation database.
Each Recording represents water elevation associated with a specific geographical point (x,y).
To compare different mareograms (signals) collected in different locations, hence with different arrival times, I need to estimate their arrival time as accurately as possible.

Comment: Cool! Sounds like a fun project.  I'll try to write an answer later (probably tomorrow), but look up CUSUM, particularly [this answer](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/3479/80).  You may have to apply it to the high-pass signal (gradient signal) or you may want to look at an "energy" measure.

Comment: I'll look at it! Seems pretty useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A gradient-based method is essentially a high-pass filter, if you think about it. ("gradient" being "derivative" for 1D signals, and the derivative being small for non-changing signals, and very high for high-frequency signals). And that's exactly how I implement it:

- Signal in
- high-pass filter
- abs()
- find first above threshold
- subtract delay of filter¹

You can do so by designing a high-pass filter using `scipy.signal.fir_filter_design` and apply it using `scipy.signal.filter`.

Another popular method, which is mainly interesting if you want to do this on a live stream of samples, is doing the same within GNU Radio, where you can take the filter taps from the filter design, and put them into a readily available FIR filter. I kind of covered that in a [blog post](http://gnuradio.org/blog/filtering-time-series-data__elemental-building-blocks/) once, and you might want to read the first chapters of the [GNU Radio Guided Tutorials](http://tutorials.gnuradio.org), too.

---

¹: this requires your filter to have constant group delay, i.e. be linear-phase.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned before, a high pass filter can add delays to your detector. If your filter is not linear-phase, the delay depends on the frequency of your signal. Another approach is the called **Onset Detection**, or a detection of a sudden burst of energy. A great paper about this is [here](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1495485/).

Answer (score 3):

I think Marcus' technique is a good approach.  However, if you want to avoid the phase-delay introduced by the high-pass filter, you could filter the signal twice.  See [Zero-phase Filtering](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/19084/applying-filter-in-scipy-signal-use-lfilter-or-filtfilt).  Granted you are filtering a given signal twice, but there is no added phase delay and, again, this is off-line data.

Comment: You can always save your data to memory and filter it twice. So this works even in online setups, as long as your filtering operations can be done under schedule.