# Signal processing techniques for an accelerometer signal?

Tags: fourier-transform, frequency-spectrum, stft

I am running some tests where I am recording accelerometer measurements.  I am looking to use elements of signal processing on this signal, but I am unsure about where to begin, or what my approach should be.

My ultimate goal is to be able to monitor the acceleration readings in real-time, and then display a notification when the `event` occurs.  As you can see around the 150,000 sample time, an `event` occurs.

- If I am monitoring this data in real time, what sort of signal processing techniques could be implemented to react to this event?
- Would a Short-Time Fourier Transform (STFT) be an option?

I am monitoring my data in Python, and they have a decent [STFT function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.stft.html#scipy.signal.stft).

The arguments of this function are as follows:

```
scipy.signal.stft(x, fs=1.0, window='hann', nperseg=256, noverlap=None, nfft=None, 
detrend=False, return_onesided=True, boundary='zeros', padded=True, axis=-1)
```

- How do I determine optimal parameters to use to process this signal?
- Are there any other methods that you folks think may help me in identifying when the `event` occurs in real-time (as opposed to just using the magnitude of the acceleration)?

[image: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/users]
[image]

**EDIT 1:**

My STFT has been added above.

Answer (score 5):

I'm wondering why the STFT pops out. To me, wouldn't a simple threshold on the signal itself or on its envelope do better / just as well, after removal of the `g` offset?

Once you decide what "measure" is best to detect your `event`, you can apply the work of Basseville and Nikiforov, that I answered [here.](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/3390/how-to-detect-fast-changes-in-signal-processing/3479#3479)

> The classic reference for that problem is [*Detection of Abrupt Changes - Theory and Application* by Basseville and Nikiforov.](http://people.irisa.fr/Michele.Basseville/kniga/)  The whole book is available as a [PDF download](http://people.irisa.fr/Michele.Basseville/kniga/kniga.pdf).
>
> My recommendation is that you read Chapter 2.2 on the [CUSUM (cumulative sum) algorithm.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUSUM)

Comment: Thanks for your comment!  I added a photo of the STFT output above.  Now, I simply ran the STFT function without much thought to the function parameters.  My acceleration is being collected at a sampling frequency of 500 Hz.  Can I use that to assist in my methods?

Comment: @Gary Thanks for adding the plot.  I'm looking at the high frequency additions that appear, but I still think the increase in amplitude appears easier to catch --- provided it captures all the versions of you `event` that you want to detect. See Fat32's answer for an example of what I'm talking about.

Comment: Hey Peter, how do you interpret the STFT plot, and put it into layman's terms.  My frequency is on the y-axis and time is on the x-axis.  So, what can I say about the frequency what is occurring at the 2.0 time-mark?

Comment: @Gary : There are two things for me: a) the appearance of harmonic content (subharmonics to the main peak before that time) and b) some widespread, non-harmonic high frequency noise. I'd look at trying to filter out that high frequency content and use it to see if it helped identifying your `event`.

Comment: The STFT occurs to you because it lets you develop a CFAR receiver when the background has steady state tones

Answer (score 5):

If this graphics represents the most typical application scenario, then I would go for some simple short window variance estimation and perform thresholding afterwards;

$$ \sigma_x^2 = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x_{ac}[n]^2$$

Where $x_{ac}[n]$ is the DC removed input signal; i.e., $x_{ac}[n] = x[n] - \bar{x}[n]$ where $\bar{x}[n]$ is the DC (mean) value of the input $x[n]$ which can locally be estimated by $$\bar{x}[n] = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x[n]$$ You could also use a DC blocking notch filter to eliminate any DC build up instead of estimating it.

Select a small enough window size $N$ appropriate for your application. You can perform the decision of the event based on a comparison of the standard deviation (square root of this computed variance estimate) to a properly selected threshold.

This will easily be computed in real-time with much less computational burden compared to a frequency domain analysis. Note that in real time application your **summation** indices should go **backwards** from the current sample (instead of the above fomulas which use a noncausal summation)

As a second efficient alternative, you could also implement a time domain **envelope detection** (followed by thresholding) to trigger the event.

Comment: “short window **variance**” is correct, i.e. $x[n]$ in your formula should actually mean $x[n] - \overline{x}$. Or, more or less equivalently, the signal could be high-pass filtered before further processing.

Comment: @leftaroundabout What is the best method of determining the cutoff frequency to build my HPF for?

Comment: @leftaroundabout the paragraph below the formula actually states that but I think it's lost in the verbose. So it seems I have to make it clear.

Comment: @Gary what HPF is that? where will you use it?

Comment: @Fat32 Sorry, I just read through your edited comment.  I like your suggestion for time domain envelope detection.  I will investigate this option.